# Android cordova InAppBrowser submit button disabled after click

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic4, keycloak

I have an Ionic 4 app that opens an external login page using a web view with  cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.

```
const url = this.createLoginUrl(this.keycloakConfig);

const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
 zoom: 'no',
 location: 'no',
 clearsessioncache: 'yes',
 clearcache: 'yes',
 hidenavigationbuttons: 'yes',
 toolbar: 'no',
 shouldPauseOnSuspend: 'yes'
 };


const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank', options);
```

On clicking the submit button of this form on the login page, the button remains disabled/grayed-out, and the screen just freezes in that state.

This worked absolutely fine, until a few days ago, and same code works fine on iOS.

Our app on the Google Play store has this issue all of a sudden, without having made any changes.

Mobile devices: Android version >=10.0.

- Is there some breaking change in the latest Android updates?
- Could this be related to latest Chrome upgrades when opening the webview?

Help or guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was related to Chrome update v85.x.
All mixed content downloads have been blocked and our app was referring to a url using "http".
As the Chrome update happened automatically on most mobile phones, the new update broke everything quite unexpectedly.

We enabled SSL everywhere to fix this issue.